# How to properly store a JSON object into a Table?

Tags: azure-data-lake

I am working on a scenario where I have invoices available in my Data Lake Store.

**Invoice example (extremely simplified):**

```
{
   "business_guid":"b4f16300-8e78-4358-b3d2-b29436eaeba8",
   "ingress_timestamp": 1523053808,
   "client":{
      "name":"Jake",
      "age":55
   },
   "transactions":[
      {
         "name":"peanut",
         "amount":100
      },
      {
         "name":"avocado",
         "amount":2
      }
   ]
}
```

All invoices are stored in ADLS, and can be queried. But, It is my desire to provide access to the same data inside an ALD DB.

I am not an expert on unstructed data: I have RDBMS background. Taking that into consideration, I can only think of 2 possible scenarios:

1. 2/3 tables - invoice, client (could be removed) and transaction. In this scenario, I would have to create an invoice ID to be able to build relationships between those tables
2. 1 table - client info could be normalized into invoice data. But, transactions could (maybe) be defined as an `SQL.ARRAY<SQL.MAP<string, object>>`

I have mainly 3 questions:

1. What is the correct way of doing so? Solution 1 seems much better structured.
2. If I go with solution 1, how do I properly create an ID (probably GUID)? Is it acceptable to require ID creation when working with ADL?
3. Is there another solution I am missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This type of question is a bit like do you prefer your sauce on the pasta or next to the pasta :). The answer is: it depends.

To answer your 3 questions more seriously:

1. #1 has the benefit of being normalized that works well if you want to operate on the data separately (e.g., just clients, just invoices, just transactions) and want to the benefits of normalization, get the right indexing, and are not limited by the rowsize limits (e.g., your array of map needs to fit into a row). So I would recommend that approach unless your transaction data is always small and you always access the data together and mainly search on the column data.
2. U-SQL per se has no understanding of the hierarchy of the JSON document. Thus, you would have to write an extractor that turns your JSON into rows in a way that it either gives you the correlation of the parent to the child (normally done by stepwise downwards navigation with cross apply) and use the key value of the parent data item as the foreign key, or have the extractor generate the key (as int or guid).

There are some sample JSON extractors on the U-SQL GitHub site (start at http://usql.io) that can get you started with the JSON to rowset conversion. Note that you will probably want to optimize the extraction at some point to be JSON Reader based so you process larger docs without loading it into memory.